# How to solve a partial derivative equation in which the RHS is the variable whose derivative is taken?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How is the following PDE solved?

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=a^2 z$$

Comment: I think you can solve it just like how you would solve the ODE, use the ansatz $z=e^{\lambda x}$, then solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: @projectilemotion So lambda will be some function of y?

Comment: If $z=z(x,y)$ here, it would be like the solution to the ODE, but replacing the arbitrary constants as arbitrary single variable functions of $y$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Hey, thanks, man. I got it.